# Cannot open Access Database

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a connection string to access an Access database which is password protected but it could not open my database and it pass an exception
i.e "Cannot open database ''.  It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt."
Please resolve this issue I search a lot but the problem still persists.
Here is my Code::

```
Public Shared DBPath As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\AFData.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=Maint@4321;"
        Public Shared Function chkdbStatus(ByRef errMessage As String) As Boolean
            Dim mydbstatus As String = False
            Using con As New OleDbConnection(DBPath)
                Try
                    con.Open()
                    If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                        errMessage = Nothing
                        mydbstatus = True
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception
                    errMessage = ex.Message
                    Return mydbstatus
                    Throw ex
                Finally
                    con.Close()
                End Try
            End Using
            Return mydbstatus
        End Function
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error and error text you're getting?

Comment: How do you have protected your database? Using Set Database Password or using a Workgroup File (MDW)?

Comment: Try using Access integrated repair tool: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/compact-and-repair-a-database-6ee60f16-aed0-40ac-bf22-85fa9f4005b2 Also, check that there's no other process / application locking the file.

Comment: Before getting too carried away, the first thing I would be checking is the connection string you are constructing is actually valid.  You may actually find that Environment.CurrentDirectory is not quite what you expect

Comment: If your database is in the same folder as the EXE then use "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\AFData.accdb". Because that's just a literal and does not require to construct, you can store it in the config file or elsewhere if appropriate.

Comment: OT, you should pretty much NEVER use `Throw ex`. By doing so, you truncate the stack trace. Just use `Throw` to throw the exception as is.

Comment: Also, your `Finally` block is pointless. The connection is created with a `Using` block so it is already guaranteed to be closed.

Comment: Finally, what's the point of rethrowing an exception after a `Return` statement? If you don't want to rethrow then don't and get rid of that inner `Return`.

Comment: Thanks John, for yours suggestions my issue is resolved now